# Django: How to use AJAX to dynamically generate form field values, based on other field dropdown options?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to autopopulate a couple of form fields based on other field dropdown values selected.

I can find several Django AJAX tutorials which show you how to send and post a form using AJAX, but I don't want to do that. I'd like to submit my form post data without AJAX. So I suppose I need to send post data on specific onclick actions, send that post data to my view/form with AJAX, and then do something (i.e. set ModelChoiceField value) with that post data in the view/form.

How would I go about doing this?

The dynamic values I want in the form:

1. Trade Price field is populated based on Coin field value. Every time a Coin field value is changed, create event.
2. Coin field change populates the Amount (a queryset based on user's coins) when "Sell" is selected on "Buysell" field.

models.py

```
 class Transactions(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)  
    coin = models.CharField(max_length = 64) # is coin a current holding? 
    buysell = models.CharField(default = 'buy', max_length = 4)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 13, decimal_places = 7)  
    trade_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    trade_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True) 
    notes = models.TextField()
```

forms.py

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    CHOICES = ((1, 'Buy'), (2, 'Sell'),)

    coin = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Coin.objects.all()) 
    buysell = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)

    field_order = ['buysell', 'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price']

    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = {'buysell', 'coin', 'amount', 'trade_price'}
```

views.py

```
def add_transaction(request):

    print(request.method)
    print("test1")

    form = TransactionForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("test2")
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("test3")
            obj = form.save(commit = False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/myportfolio/')
        else: 
            print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'myportfolio/add_transaction.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: How will you retrieve data from the 2 new forms?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There are no "new" forms?

Comment: my bad, I thought you wanted to autogenerate new form based on a specific field value

Comment: `on change` event for the choices field, attach it with ajax, and refresh the concerned part of the DOM, you can do it like that

Comment: Found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642265/3219210